# Drawing ISINs of a ticker via Python-Bloomberg API

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi, pdblp

I have a question about drawing ISIN's of goverment bonds in python. Up to my knowledge the state of the art package for this is "blp" in python which is described as the next iteration of pdblp. What I want to do is to get all the ISIN's of a goverment ticker like "DBR Govt". I know that in Excel BQL exists which would do that. One does not have access to it in python.

Is there a way to do this task with "blp"? I know that "pdblp" has a function "bsrch" which could do it, but I am not able to get access to this package. Or is there another way I can do my task in python with another package?

Thanks for some ideas.

Comment: The underlying package for accessing Bloomberg through client-side tools in Python is `blpapi` provided by Bloomberg themselves. See https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/ and read the Python install section. Now, this api is robust but not terribly user-friendly as it is designed to handle a wide variety of requests for data. Several 3rd-party packages have been developed to hide some of the workings of `blpapi`. There is `pdblp`, `xbbg` and several others, but all rely on `blpapi` under the covers.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `bsrch` but it sounds like the `//blp/instruments` service might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

@DS_London, thanks for the prod to look at blp/instruments. I dug into the Bloomberg for Enterprise Open API Services & schemas reference guide (PDF), which is very hard to find. I tried to find it again, but no luck. On page 75 I found the government lookup request and tweaked some of my existing code to get it to work. I had created separate functions for some of this code, but I didn't bother with this test. I thought it might help me to see if there was some way to pull a list of securities from an SRCH, but not sure if I can pull that off.

EDIT: If you are a BBG user, you can find the PDF referenced above at WAPI -> API Developer's Guide -> Reference Guide: Services and Schemas.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

import blpapi

SESSION_STARTED = blpapi.Name("SessionStarted")
SESSION_STARTUP_FAILURE = blpapi.Name("SessionStartupFailure")

# Removed optparse.OptionParser because it was deprecated.
def parseCmdLine():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Retrieve reference data.')
    parser.add_argument('-a',
                      '--ip',
                      dest='host',
                      help='server name or IP (default: %(default)s)',
                      metavar='ipAddress',
                      default='localhost')
    parser.add_argument('-p',
                      dest='port',
                      type=int,
                      help='server port (default: %(default)s)',
                      metavar='tcpPort',
                      default=8194)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args

args = parseCmdLine()

# Fill SessionOptions
sessionOptions = blpapi.SessionOptions()
sessionOptions.setServerHost(args.host)
sessionOptions.setServerPort(args.port)

# Create a Session
session = blpapi.Session(sessionOptions)

# Start a Session
session.start()

session.openService("//blp/instruments")
instrumentsDataService = session.getService("//blp/instruments")

request = instrumentsDataService.createRequest("govtListRequest")

# request.asElement().setElement('partialMatch', True)
request.asElement().setElement('query', 'DBR')
request.asElement().setElement('ticker', '')
request.asElement().setElement('maxResults', 10)

session.sendRequest(request)

try:
    # Process received events
    while(True):
        # We provide timeout to give the chance to Ctrl+C handling:
        ev = session.nextEvent(500)
        # below msg.messageType == GovtListResponse
        for msg in ev:
            if msg.messageType() == "GovtListResponse":
                if msg.hasElement("responseError"):
                    print(msg.toString())
                if msg.hasElement("results"):
                    data = msg.getElement("results")
                    print(data)
        # Response completly received, so we could exit
        if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE:
            break
finally:
    # Stop the session
    session.stop()

>>>results[] = {
    results = {
        parseky = "BT245031 Corp"
        name = "Bundesrepublik Deutschland Bundesanleihe"
        ticker = "DBR"
    }
    results = {
        parseky = "BP980366 Corp"
        name = "Bundesrepublik Deutschland Bundesanleihe"
        ticker = "DBR"
    }
    results = {
        parseky = "BR246981 Corp"
        name = "Bundesrepublik Deutschland Bundesanleihe"
        ticker = "DBR"
    }
    results = {
        parseky = "BN261261 Corp"
        name = "Bundesrepublik Deutschland Bundesanleihe"
        ticker = "DBR"
    }
    results = {
        parseky = "AW416188 Corp"
        name = "Bundesrepublik Deutschland Bundesanleihe"
        ticker = "DBR"
    }
    results = {
        parseky = "ZR097974 Corp"
        name = "Bundesrepublik Deutschland Bundesanleihe"
        ticker = "DBR"
    }
    results = {
        parseky = "AP115404 Corp"
        name = "Bundesrepublik Deutschland Bundesanleihe"
        ticker = "DBR"
    }
    results = {
        parseky = "AQ584649 Corp"
        name = "Bundesrepublik Deutschland Bundesanleihe"
        ticker = "DBR"
    }
    results = {
        parseky = "AL997549 Corp"
        name = "Bundesrepublik Deutschland Bundesanleihe"
        ticker = "DBR"
    }
    results = {
        parseky = "ZP220656 Corp"
        name = "Bundesrepublik Deutschland Bundesanleihe"
        ticker = "DBR"
    }
}
```